# Managing http sessions, nodeJS

Tags: node.js, cookies, webserver

I am building an HTTP server in nodeJS (homework assignment), and I need to manage HTTP sessions with cookies - for each session I send a cookie with `UUID` (string ID) and then when I get it back I reset the session's timer.

My question: should I open a session for each request (i.e. even an image/css request for example) or for each page?

This is my code now:

```
socket.on('data',function(data) {
    //some code
    // if no UUID exsit in request, create one for it
    var request = new REQUEST.Request(data, resourceMap, rootFolder); //
    //response will send the UUID created/sent in request
    var response = new RESPONSE.Response(socket,request);
    session(request); // look for uuid from request in data base
}
```

Right now when I load a page, the `html` request is always the first and a new UUID is created for it, but not for the next requests (images etc) in that page.
Also, when I hit a link to another page no UUID is created.

Any ideas why? Where is the best place to check for an existing UUID and add one if its not there? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a session for one session. :) Not each request.

In the session you can set an UUID.

There are plenty of resources out there to help you. If your professor has allowed you to use libraries, I'd highly suggest checking your options. This is just a few: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules

Because it's homework question, I think it's best that you only get some direction to the 'answer'

Good luck